# Moving from the last object level to the first one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, structure

I have such array of objects:

```
var Categories = [
    {n:'1st category',u:1,s:[{n:'Sub category',u:2,s:[{n:'Sub sub category',u:3,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 2',u:4,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 3',u:5,s:[]}]},{n:'Sub category',u:6,s:[{n:'Sub sub category',u:7,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 2',u:8,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 3',u:9,s:[]}]},{n:'Sub category',u:10,s:[{n:'Sub sub category',u:11,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 2',u:12,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 3',u:13,s:[]}]}]},
    {n:'2nd category',u:14,s:[{n:'Sub category',u:15,s:[{n:'Sub sub category',u:16,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 2',u:17,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 3',u:18,s:[]}]}]},
    {n:'3rd category',u:19,s:[{n:'Sub category',u:20,s:[{n:'Sub sub category',u:21,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 2',u:22,s:[]},{n:'Sub sub category 3',u:23,s:[]}]}]}
];
```

**Legend:** n - name, u - id, s - sub categories (innter categories) which also contains n, u, and s.

So the depth of sub categories is all the time changing and is not fixed. Is it possible to do a function which finds all mother/parent categories names?

Like, If I would search for id 2 (u=2), it would find me u1, so the way till Sub category is: 1st category > Sub category, if I would look for u=6: Sub sub category > Sub category > 1st category.

I probably should use recursive function for this, but I can't think a logic for that.. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot find the *parent* or *holder* of a property in JavaScript (unless you keep track of it somewhere in the property value itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
findCat = function(u, obj) {
    if(obj.u == u)
        return [];
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.s.length; i++) {
        var p = findCat(u, obj.s[i]);
        if(p)
            return p.concat([obj.s[i].n])
    }
    return null;
}

path = findCat(22, {s:Categories})
```

Result:

```
[
 "Sub sub category 2",
 "Sub category",
 "3rd category"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem would be to restructure your list into an id-based map that has both objects with a parent-id member and objects without (so those are super level categories).

Your map would then be something like:

```
{
    1: {n: '1st Category'}
    2: {n: 'Sub category', parent-id: 1}
    3: {n: 'Sub sub category', parent-id: 2}
    14: {n: '2nd Category'}
}
```

That would make finding routes to certain categories trivial and getting a list of top level categories would just be filtering on whether an object has a parent-id field or not.

Edit: Whether this is attractive or not might of course depend on whether it's fast enough for your implementation and what function you need to optimize.